# Why does Angular 2 remove index.html from link and redirect to my routing link?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using a router in Angular 2 to redirect my components. However, when I start my server and launch the webpage, localhost:4200/index.html gets redirected to localhost:4200/myComponent.

I cannot refresh the server because it says /myComponent is not a valid resource. My server only handles /index.html.

How can I get index.html to stay?

Comment: You have to redirect everything to index.html. Only then the router is able to actually rout. https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Comment: I see, so it looks like I need to configure my server to redirect. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain the need for that so we can help you accordingly? if you provide an example will be better